# Relacion muchos a muchos en Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Tengo esta estructura

```
user
role_user
roles
```

Tengo la entidad `User`, `roles`.La entidad r`ole_user` **NO**, porque no es "necesaria"
Cuando cree la migración para la tabla `role_user`, le agregue algunos campos adicionales, ejemplo `fechaInicioRol` ,`fechaFinRol`.
Ahora bien, cuando yo me obtengo el usuario y sus roles

```
 $usuarios=Usuario::where('idUsuario',"=",$id)->with('roles')->get();
```

Esto me trae una `collecion` de `roles`, pero no puedo acceder a los campos que mencione antes de la tabla `role_user`, se entiende?

Answer (score 3):

Si defines campos adicionales en la tabla intermedia y deseas obtenerlos, debes definirlos en la relación con el método `withPivot`:

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role')->withPivot('column1', 'column2');
```

Para acceder a ellos, lo haces por medio del objeto pivot:

```
echo $role->pivot->column1;
```

En la documentación encuentras todo: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Answer (score 2):

Si como mencionas que ya tienes funcionando `$usuarios=Usuario::where('idUsuario',"=",$id)->with('roles')->get();` entonces lo que debes de hacer es: agregar `withPivot()` a tu funcion de relacion.

Es decir que dentro de tu modelo `Usuario` debes de tener una funcion llamada **roles**, entonces el codigo seria:

```
public function roles(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class,'role_user','user_id','role_id')->withPivot('fechaInicioRol ', 'fechaFinRol');
}
```

Luego tu consulta quedaria e la misma forma:

```
$usuarios=Usuario::where('idUsuario',"=",$id)->with('roles')->get();
```

Y posterior puedes utilizar `pivot` para acceder a los datos.

Por ejemplo en `foreach`

```
foreach($usuarios as $user){
    echo   $user->role->pivot->fechaInicioRol;
}
```

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: No me esta funcionando
en este codigo
public function roles(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class,'role_user','user_id','role_id')->c
}
donde pones public function roles(){
   withPivot('fechaInicioRol ', 'fechaFinRol');
}
no iria las claves foraneas, osea 
withPivot('idUsuario ', 'idRol');
??

Comment: Basicamente withPivot extrae los datos de la tabla pivote, asi que ahi entra los datos que necesites de la tabla pivote

Answer (score 1):

Pude solucionarlo, tenia un error de concepto , cuando se crea en el modelo la relacion con la tabla pivot, no se pone las claves foraneas, sino los campos que se quieren tomar de la tabla pivot

```
->withPivot('fechaInicioRol ', 'fechaFinRol');
```

de esa manera esta bien, y luego se recupera:

```
$usuario->roles->pivot->fechaInicioRol;
```

Gracias a todos por la ayuda

Comment: ¿Solucionó tu problema, @Lucho? Por favor no olvides marcar la respuesta como aceptada si tu problema se solucionó. Puedes hacerlo marcando el ✓ en la parte izquierda de la respuesta (se pondrá verde, ganarás 2 puntos de reputación y podrías acceder a [nuevos privilegios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)). ¡Mira [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) si tienes alguna duda!